# Guess me riddle

Tags: riddle

I move very slowly at an imperceptible rate, 
although I take my time, I am never late.
 I accompany life, and survive past demise,
 I am viewed with esteem in many women's eyes.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> Hair

I move very slowly at an imperceptible rate,

> It is like 0.5 inches per month.

although I take my time, I am never late.

> Almost everyone has hair.

I accompany life, and survive past demise,

> There are still some skeletons with hair on them.

I am viewed with esteem in many women's eyes.

> Girls like to have nice hair.

Comment: Good one ! I like the thinking

Comment: Oh my ears and whiskers, sometimes it is late, late, late!

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> Diamond

I move very slowly at an imperceptible rate

> Creating a diamond is a very long process

although I take my time, I am never late

> Diamonds form in the exact time they should

I accompany life, and survive past demise

> Diamonds are apart of life (i.e. jewelry for birthday presents).  Jewelry is often passed down through inheritance, so, effectively, diamonds survive one's demise by survivor with an heir.

I am viewed with esteem in many women's eyes.

> Women, stereotypically, enjoy diamonds and want to be presented with an engagement ring (traditionally a diamond ring)

Comment: Great try but not it moreover, what about the line' I survive past demise'?

Comment: @Quark-epoch Updated

Comment: No,that is not the meaning of demise, but well tried. Here , ROT13(urer, qrzvfr zrnaf uhzna qrngu abg nal aba- yvivat guvat'f qrfgehpgvba)

Comment: @Quark-epoch, I understand what you are getting at (without the hint :-) )

Comment: hmmm.. lets see what you come up with

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> A star in the sky.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Unfortunately, this puzzle already has [an accepted answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73532/guess-me-riddle/73535#73535). Also, note that answers are usually hidden with ">!"  tags ([spoiler notation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers)). QuantumTwinkie already has done this for this answer. Why not [take the tour](/tour) for an easy badge?

Comment: Well tried, but no problem. +1 from me. Great thinking though not the answer