# Guess Me riddle #2

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

[View the first part here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73532/guess-me-riddle)

The word is broken down into parts

My first part is a small character in a book and a movie

My second part is related to company 

My third part is related to a rabbit

My whole is a sweet

> **Hint 1:**
>  The rabbit is from a book
>  
>  **Hint 2:**
>  Expelliarmus

What am I?

Comment: I notice you used sweet instead of candy, does this mean it is a UK based sweet? Or do you mean like a sweet pastry in the US?

Comment: Quark-epoch is an Indian. It might be an Indian sweet @AHKieran. :)

Comment: @KratiGarg I may be indian but this particular one is a global delicacy

Comment: Hi Why not join Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet?

Comment: I have an entry there @OmegaKrypton

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is simply...

> **Chocolate**

My first part is a small character in a book and a movie

> **Cho** Chang, Harry Potter's love interest in book 5. *[Hint 2: Expelliarmus]*

My second part is related to company

> **Co**, short for company

My third part is related to a rabbit

> The rabbit from Alice in Wonderland is always **late**. *[Hint 1: The rabbit is from a book]*

My Whole is sweet \ global delicacy

> Yup. :)

Comment: Well done , A pinpoint answer

Answer (score 2):

The only clue that gives me any ideas is the related to a rabbit one. Here are some of my thoughts. Still have no idea what the answer is though.

> some sort of bun. Like a cinnamon bun maybe.
> Or it could be talking about eggs, since they are related to the Easter Bunny. Cadbury Creme Eggs? But I don't see how that would relate to the other hints. >.<

Comment: Well tried! But off the mark, Nevertheless , see hint 1 and try looking for something else

Comment: Look at Hint 2 to know more

Comment: You could be on to something. rot13: uggc://guruhatretnzrf.jvxvn.pbz/jvxv/Pvaan

Answer (score 1):

Well...

> To be honest, I don't think this is it. But, might as well anyways right?
>  How about:
>  Marshmallow Bunny

Character:

> 

Company:

> I mean, there is probably a company called "Mallow" somewhere in the world. Or, if it's the other meaning of company then... Well a Mallow is a flower, and flowers tend to grow in groups, thus with company right? eh? eh? K', maybe it's a stretch but...

Rabbit:

> A bunny rabbit...

Comment: You are completely off the track , See hint 1

Comment: Your sweet answer is appealing as [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) Irebavpn Znef vf cynlrq ol 5 sg 1 va vapu npgbe, U&Z vf n snfuvba pbzcnal, Znyybj vf n enoovg sebz Jngrefuvc Qbja.

Comment: @Tom That looks like an _answer_. Why not post it as one?

Comment: Woah! Great thought @Tom Post it as an answer, If I don't get the expected answer within a week then I will mark yours as correct

Comment: Thank @Quark-epoch and Dorrulf (welcome to update with any of this). I'm intrigued and will think further about your sweet question.

Comment: Look at hint 2 to know more

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

My first part is a small character in a book and a movie.

> Background-->Back/ Supporting-->Supp 
>  (NOT The letter 'a' and 'o' is in both "a book" and "a movie", therefore the first part is 'ao'.)

My third part is related to a rabbit.

> Hare-y Potter? (Expelliarmus) (NOT Hazel? White Rabbit?)(NOT Peter Rabbit) (NOT Bun/ Hare)

Comment: 1>a part may contain more than one alphabets also.

Comment: 2> It is related to a rabbit (Look at Hint 1)

Comment: Edited, How about now?

Comment: No, still far away and by the way character doesn't refer to an alphabet but it refers to a person playing a role in a book as well as a movie

Comment: Look at hint 2 to know more

Answer (score 1):

I have seriously no idea how I thought about this but the first thing comes into my mind is.

My Answer

> Pineapple

The word is broken down into parts

> It's not in two parts but we can say like Pine Apple

My first part is a small character in a book and a movie

> I was thinking about Chris Pine

My second part is related to company

> **Apple** is a company too.

My third part is related to a rabbit

> Rabbit may surely like this. :D

My whole is a sweet

> Is Pineapple sweet in taste ?

*Sorry if this is totally wrong.*

Comment: Well tried, The word is broken down into 3 parts and the last line is a description of the word so frame your answer accordingly ,Moreover Pinapples are sour-sweet, Look at Hint 1

Comment: Look at hint 2 to know more

Comment: Ohk I just quick created an answer, but thanks for pointing it out.