# Guess Me riddle #3

Tags: mathematics, word, wordplay

[View the last part here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75335/guess-me-riddle-2)

Guess the word

Sir, I bear a rhyme excelling
In mystic force and magic spelling
Celestial sprites elucidate
All my own striving can't relate

What am I?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a _puzzle_. (For the avoidance of doubt: yes, I know the answer.)

Comment: Or locate they who can cogitate
and so finally terminate. finis. http://pages.intnet.mu/cueboy/education/maths/pi/england.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is

> a well known mnemonic for the digits of $\pi$. (Count the letters in each word.)

Answer (score 0):

I got

> hocus pocus

but I feel like I'm missing something.

> It rhymes and it is used to invoke magical effects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it made me think of

> Light

But, if @GarethMcCaughan is correct, then this is pretty moot.

Sir, I bear a rhyme excelling

> Not a rhyme unfortunately, but a synonym for excel is shine

In mystic force and magic spelling

> This statement along with the mathematics tag makes me think of a math formula relevant to light. Perhaps one related to Electromagnetic ration specifically?

Celestial sprites elucidate

> Celestial: Of the sky
>  sprite: a faint flash, typically red, sometimes emitted in the upper atmosphere over a thunderstorm owing to the collision of high-energy electrons with air molecules.
>  elucidate: make (something) clear; explain
>  This makes me think of a star, and thus the light emitted from one.

All my own striving can't relate

> We still struggle to fully understand all the states of light. Also, we aren't capable of travel at the speed of light yet.