# Guess me riddle #4

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge

[View the last puzzle here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75452/guess-me-riddle-3)

The word is a four letter word which is in the oxford dictionary

My first letter is related to root-nodules

My second letter is a start

My third letter is related to Loki

My fourth is the same as the second

In whole I am known to hide many secrets

 What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is:

> **NASA**

*My first letter is related to root-nodules*

> [Root nodules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_nodule) are to do with plant roots and Nitrogen, the chemical symbol for which is **N**.

*My second letter is a start*

> The start of the alphabet is **A**.

*My third letter is related to Loki*

> Loki likes to turn into a snake (to trick Thor, among other things). Snakes are often associated with the letter **S** due to their shape and they start with S.

*My fourth is the same as the second*

> Again, **A**.

*In whole I am known to hide many secrets*

> **NASA** are thought to be hiding secrets of aliens and the like.

Comment: Woah! That was fast well done!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

> lama

My first letter is related to root-nodules

> mostly exist on **l**egumes

My second letter is a start

> Beginning of the alphabet

My third letter is related to Loki

> god of **m**ischief

My fourth is the same as the second

> a again

In whole I am known to hide many secrets

> Many think Tibetan lamas hold many secrets

Comment: You are correct about the second and the fouth letter but wrong about the first and the third