# One at a Time Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge

This riddle borrows a format from [Guess me riddle #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75509/guess-me-riddle-4) by [Quark-epoch](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51989/quark-epoch).

---

The word is a four letter word which is in the oxford dictionary

> My first letter is ***a green cut-out vital sign***.
>
> My second is ***however, a shelled kernel***.
>
> My third is, *out loud*, ***top of the game***.
>
> My fourth is ***a dame’s healed tree organ***.
>
> My whole is ***what you simply read***.

Now answer me this, what am I?

Note + Hint:

> This might require a ***little*** botanical knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try for:

> Post

My first letter is a green cut-out vital sign.

> @rhsquared has suggested P

My second is however, a shelled kernel.

> Perhaps an OS, or operating system. Thus O
>  Per @jafe however is synonymous with though, and shelled kernel is also a nut, thus though + nut, or doughnut (phonetically similar), or O (based on shape of doughnut)

My third is, out loud, top of the game.

> <s>Shrug*. Dunno if I'm supposed to get the letter by saying "top of the game" out loud (and identifying something sounding the same), or if it's related to a sport like baseball etc.</s>
>  Again, per @jafe the top card in many games is the ace, which sounds like "s"

My fourth is a dame’s healed tree organ.

> My best guess here is tea which is phonetically similar to the letter T. Healed tree organ make me think of cured plant parts such as leaves, which are used to make tea. Or possibly, by dame's you're referring to flowers which have petals which when dried/treated/cured can also be used in tea.

My whole is what you simply read.

> We read posts here on this site.

Special thanks to:

> @rhsquared and especially to @jafe. Would also like to find a way to share with them :)

Edit: Apologies for the delay, update is finally here.

Comment: You got the whole word right but the explanation for the second are wrong and you didn’t go into much detail on the last one. As for the third one, you are on the right track; what's left is just finding the right word. Still +1 for figuring out the whole word!

Comment: For the second, rot13[ubjrire vf "gubhtu" naq furyyvat gur svefg gjb naq ynfg guerr yrggref yrnirf "b"]?

Comment: Third: rot13[gur gbc pneq va znal tnzrf vf gur npr, juvpu fbhaqf yvxr "f"]?

Comment: @jafe That’s an interesting way to solve it and rot13(lbh ner ba gur evtug genpx gb hfr gur jbeq "gubhtu" ohg qbrf furyyrq xreary nyfb zrna fbzrguvat bhgfvqr gur ernyz bs cebtenzzvat ynathntr?)

Comment: @jafe Third one is correct and it's also being used as a sport term too.

Comment: @Chrone gubhtu + ahg = qbhtuahg = b?

Comment: @jafe Since you are the one who got all explanations correct but doesn’t have your own answer, I don’t know what I should do here. Should I wait for Dorrulf to edit their answer or is there any way I can give credit to you?

Comment: @Chrone Better to give it to Dorrulf who found the correct answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

> I think the first letter is possible 'P' because peas is part of the pulses family and pulse is a vital sign. Peas are green and you need to 'cut it out' from its shell.

Comment: Yes, you hit the nail on the head on this one!

Answer (score 0):

I will go for

> Read

My first letter is a green cut-out vital sign.

> The letter r looks like a green shoot, a vital sign

My second is however, a shelled kernel.

> The letter e looks like a shelled kernel

My third is, out loud, top of the game.

> The letter a, perhaps is the first letter of the alphabet?

My fourth is a dame’s healed tree organ.

> Not sure but I find the letter d in dame’s and healed

My whole is what you simply read

> I am reading the word read!

Comment: Sorry, this is not the correct solution. My solution is more playful on word than this.