# Start with a table

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Inspired by [One at a Time Riddle by Chrone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75521/one-at-a-time-riddle)

Entry into Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet

> Start with a table at the left corner on the top
>   Add another letter and to another corner you hop
>   With the third letter, in there the Norse treat you dead
>   Plus the fourth letter, in there all people see you dead
>   The last letter you add, and “Welcome, my dear puzzler”!

What is the word?

Comment: Please don't keep adding your name into question titles. Your username and avatar already appear on the post - [signatures and taglines are strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/278659) even in the body of the post, and in the title they're *certainly* unnecessary noise.

Comment: ok, but please keep the numbers, thanks!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Adding names may be part of the puzzle.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat It may be, but when someone titles all of their puzzles as things like "One at a Time Riddle 001 by KrOmega (new try)", that's not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Start with a table at the left corner on the top*

> H - the atomic symbol for Hydrogen on the top left corner of the periodic table

*Add another letter and to another corner you hop*

> HE - the atomic symbol for Helium on the top right corner of the periodic table

*With the third letter, in there the Norse treat you dead*

> HEL - one of the Viking realms of the dead

*Plus the fourth letter, in there all people see you dead*

> HELL - does this one need an explanation?

*The last letter you add, and “Welcome, my dear puzzler”!*

> HELLO - also pretty clear

Comment: Sorry for my super late tick, well done!